# I want to run a R code in batch and wait for user input

Tags: r, batch-file, input

I want to run a program in batch and I want it to wait for the user input in the program.

This is what I have:

```
library('XLConnect')
FolderPath<-"C:/Documents/Testing/"
load(paste('C:/Documents/Testing/Program.ml',sep=''));Run()
```

This code is named Test.R, and it calls a compiled file that runs a function that does what I need. I need to have some inputs in this exercise, so I wanted to ask for the user to input some dates.

The program should do something like this:

```
What are the years for this simulation?
```

Then the user enter:

```
>2001, 2002, 2003, 2004
```

The program will save this vector in variable, lets call y.
Then, when I load the compiled function, I will use y.
The problem is that I run this R code in cmd batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yukio, try the function `readline` (documentation [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readline.html)) as in the following example, in which a user inputs two years separated by a comma.

```
> years = readline('What are the years for this simulation? ')
What are the years for this simulation? 2001, 2002
> years = as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(years, ",")))
> years
[1] 2001 2002
```

By the way, your English is great!

Comment: I've tried, unfortunately readline() doesn't work when running in batch. I'm really struggling to get this part of my program done. tks for the compliment!

Comment: For the record, as of 12/2021, this still does not work

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand (someone please correct me if this is wrong), but you can't send messages to the user at the command line when executing a script with R CMD BATCH (it writes all input and output to an .Rout file). But executing a script with Rscript.exe does in fact let you send stuff to stdout. However, in order to get input from a user when executing with Rscript.exe, you need to use `file('stdin')` as the connection to your input function, which, funny enough, won't work if you then try to run the script from the R interpreter with the `source` function. Here's an example that showing you how to prompt the user for a series of comma separated years, regardless of whether the script runs with Rscript.exe or the `source` function in interactive mode.

```
con <- if (interactive()) stdin() else file('stdin')
message('what are the years')
years <- scan(file=con, sep=',', nlines=1, quiet=TRUE)
print(years)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can deal easily with user inputs in a batch file not in the R. 
You create a batch file , say `launcher.bat` , like this for example

```
ECHO I am Rscript launcher
set /p years= What are the years for this simulation?
cd R_SCRIPT_PATH
Rscript youscript.R %years%
```

The user can write as many years he want, it will go in the variable years. Then in your script you parse this variable to set it as a valid list of years.

Comment: I'm feeling really stupid here. I didn't understand very well. How should I call this .bat in my R code?

Comment: :) I am using Rscript not R CMD BATCH to launch the script. Maybe see [may answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721872/making-commandargs-comma-delimited-or-parsing-spaces/13722382#13722382) to understand better.

Comment: Hmmm... I get it, but this might be a problem as the whole program is running with CMD BATCH.